# Files owner on Joomla website

Tags: apache, joomla, ftp, permissions, file-ownership

I need some suggestions about Joomla's files and folders ownership.
I'm working with a Joomla 2.5 website, hosted on a linux-apache server which hasn't suPHP module.
After one year of usage some files are owned by apache-user, and others by the ftp user.
I request to give the ownership of all files to the ftp user, but joomla (the apache user, after all) can't update system, install extensions or upload images.
How can i set the ownership of files?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to talk to your hosting provider to change the file/folder ownership for you (which they should do), else if you are managing the server yourself , then you can do this using the following SSH command:

```
chgrp -R OWNER FOLDER
```

- `-R` means recursive so it will also change the ownership for any sub directories and files
- `OWNER` is the name of the server which you will need to add
- `FOLDER` is simply the name of the folder you wish to apply this change to.

As for the command line tool, I like to use [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Hope this helps